# Is unused object available for garbage collection when it's still visible in stack?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

In the following example there are two functionally equivalent methods:

```
public class Question {

    public static String method1() {
        String s = new String("s1");
        // some operations on s1
        s = new String("s2");
        return s;
    }

    public static String method2() {
        final String s1 = new String("s1");
        // some operations on s1
        final String s2 = new String("s2");
        return s2;
    }
}
```

however in first(`method1`) of them string "s1" is clearly available for garbage collection before `return` statement. In second(`method2`) string "s1" is still reachable (though from code review prospective it's not used anymore).

My question is - is there anything in jvm spec which says that once variable is unused down the stack it could be available for garbage collection?

***EDIT:***
Sometimes variables can refer to object like fully rendered image and that have impact on memory.

I'm asking because of practical considerations. I have large chunk of memory-greedy code in one method and thinking if I could help JVM (a bit) just by splitting  this method into few small ones.

I really prefer code where no reassignment is done since it's easier to read and reason about.

***UPDATE***: per [jls-12.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1):

> Java compiler or code generator may choose to set a variable or parameter that will no longer be used to null to cause the storage for such an object to be potentially reclaimable sooner

So it looks like it's possible for GC to claim object which still visible. I doubt, however that this optimisation is done during offline compilation (it would screw up debugging) and most likely will be done by JIT.

Comment: Is your question about method1 or method2? Delete the other method, because it makes your question *less* clear.

Comment: When `dead code elimination` takes place then `new String("s1");` may not even be created and therefore does not have to be garbage collected. However the VM must be able to recognize that `new String("s1")` does not have side-effects. For such a special, well known, highly optimized JDK class I wouldn't be surprised if this is done.

Comment: @FabianBarney - A VM will generally assume (in fact, must assume) that a `new` operation may have side-effects.  It would be a special case of a special case to do dead code elimination on the `new String` operation.  Possible but unlikely.

Comment: @erickson I put method names in round brackets so it's more clear what I'm referring to. I still prefer to leave two methods in questions since that gives side-by-side comparison.

Comment: Splitting a long method is nearly always a good idea, so do it. Single assignment is a good principle most of the time, too. In case when neither is good, consider scoping (enclosing parts of the method in braces).

Comment: @FabianBarney `new String("s1");` isn't necessarily dead(it is in this particular example, but it's just for simplicity). It might be used further down in the method. My point is that it's GC-collectable/reachable before `return` statement and I don't know what java spec says about this case.

Comment: @Petro Semeniuk: But I do (learnt just now), see [JLS-12.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1): "may choose to set a variable or parameter that will no longer be used to null". See also Hot Licks' answer. Actually, the JVM may chose not to create an object, if the semantics stays the same (like when used a temporary like e.g. `Pair` for returning multiple values).

Comment: @maaartinus yeah, looks like your reference answers my question. Good to know that optimisation is actually done at compile stage. Feel free to put that in answer!

Comment: It should be noted that the spec says precious little about "storage reclamation".  I've read, in fact, that a conforming JVM is not actually required to have GC (of any sort), but I've never tried to parse the spec (and the Sun/Oracle unwritten rules) to see in what conditions this might be true.

Comment: @maaartinus if optimisation is done at compiling stage then it's getting interesting during debugging. If I put breakpoint on return statement, will I found variables to be null, though from source it clearly not null?

Comment: @Petro Semeniuk: I wouldn't say that optimization gets done when compiling into bytecode. Anyway, this is something easy to find out. Concerning the debugger, I guess it'd prevent this optimization, but I don't know... I don't even know if it actually happens, I only know it's allowed.

Comment: @maaartinus Yeah... I think what they mean under compilation is JIT compiler(not .java => .class one). In that case optimisation still could happen, and at the same time method could be recompiled to it's original implementation once somebody connected to java process via remote socket.

Comment: @Petro Semeniuk: Yes, this makes sense. Maybe you want to investigate what the JVM does by trying it out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because your code could conceivably retrieve it and do something with it, and the abstract JVM does not consider what code is coming ahead. However, a very, very, very clever optimizing JVM might analyze the code ahead and find that there is no way `s1` could ever be referenced, and garbage collect it. You definitely can't count on this, though.

Comment: Incorrect.  Even at the interpreter level a data flow analysis has been done (as part of method verification), and it's entirely possible (though unlikely) for the interpreter to null the reference or otherwise make the object available for collection "early".  At the JITC level this action is actually quite likely, as a side-effect of normal optimization.  There is no architectural restriction on this.

Comment: @Hot Licks: AFAIK the interpreter allocates a slot for each variable, so I don't think it could happen (clearing it for the sake of GC sound rather improbable). I guess that JIT can do this rather often (e.g., using a single register for multiple variable with non-overlapping lifetimes).

Comment: @maaartinus - True, the interpreter allocates a slot for each variable.  (Well, sort of -- javac may actually do some liveness analysis and have variables "share" slots, so there's no guarantee that the interpreter slot is "dedicated".)  But the JVM does do a dataflow as a part of method verification, so in theory the information (that the stack slot is "dead") is available to pass to GC.

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about the interpreter, then in the second case S1 remains "referenced" until the method exits and the stack frame is rolled up.  (That is, in the standard interpreter -- it's entirely possible for GC to use liveness info from method verification.  And, in addition (and more likely), javac may do its own liveness analysis and "share" interpreter slots based on that.)

In the case of the JITC, however, an even mildly optimizing one might recognize that S1 is unused and recycle that register for S2.  Or it might not.  The GC will examine register contents, and if S1 has been reused for something else then the old S1 object will be reclaimed (if not otherwise referenced).  If the S1 location has not been reused then the S1 object *might not* be reclaimed.

"Might not" because, depending on the JVM, the JITC may or may not provide the GC with a map of where object references are "live" in the program flow.  And this map, if provided, may or may not precisely identify the end of the "live range" (the last point of reference) of S1.  Many different possibilities.

Note that this potential variability does not violate any Java principles -- GC is not required to reclaim an object at the earliest possible opportunity, and there's no practical way for a program to be sensitive to precisely when an object is reclaimed.

Answer (score 1):

VM is free to optimized the code to nullify `s1` before method exit (as long as it's correct), so `s1` might be eligible for garbage earlier.

However that is hardly necessary. Many method invocations must have happened before the next GC; all the stack frames have been cleared anyway, no need to worry about a specific local variable in a specific method invocation.

As far as Java the language is concerned, garbages can live forever without impact program semantics. That's why JLS hardly talks about garbage at all.

Comment: There are very rarely individual situations where a "dead" object reference in a long-lived stack frame "hangs onto" a mega-object and causes heap size issues.  This is kind of a one-in-a-million situation, though.  (It should be noted that even if a reference has passed out of inner `{}` scope, it may still appear "live" to GC.)

Comment: @HotLicks can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

> in first of them string "s1" is clearly available for garbage collection before return statement

It isn't clear at all. I think you are confusing 'unused' with 'unreachable'. They aren't *necessarily* the same thing.

Formally speaking the variable is live until its enclosing scope terminates, so it isn't available for garbage collection until then.

However "a Java compiler or code generator may choose to set a variable or parameter that will no longer be used to null to cause the storage for such an object to be potentially reclaimable sooner" [JLS #12.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1).

Comment: @downviter Your explanation please.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but the object can be reclaimed as soon as there are no possible future references.

Answer (score 0):

Basically stack frames and static area are considered as roots by GC. So if object is referenced from any stack frame its considered alive. The problem with reclaiming some objects from active stack frame is that GC works in parallel with application(mutator). How do you think GC should find out that object is unused while method is in progress? That would require a synchronization which would be VERY heavy and complex, in fact this will break the idea of GC to work in parallel with mutator. Every thread might keep variables in processor registers. To implement your logic, they should also be added to GC roots. I cant even imagine how to implement it.

To answer you question. If you have any logic which produces a lot of objects which are unused in the future, separate it to a distinct method. This is actually a good practice.

You should also take int account optimizations by JVM(like EJP pointed out). There is also an escape analysis, which might prevent object from heap allocation at all. But rely your codes performance on them is a bad practice