# Garbage Collection and InComplete Constructed Object

Tags: java, constructor, garbage-collection

This may be a very naive Question?

Suppose i have Class Something like this

```
class SlowConstructor {

     private final int a;
     private final String unReachableString;

     public SlowConstructor(String random) {
            unReachableString = "I am not reachable will GC will collect me " + random;
            Thread.sleep(1000*3600); // ignoring Exception check for readbility
            a = 100;
            Thread.sleep(1000*3600);
     }
}
```

So my question is if i create Many Objects of SlowConstructor (let say 50 in diff threads) and as you can see each Constructor will take two hours to complete. The String reference in SlowConstructor **unReachableString**  is not reachable from any code for around two hours. If GC runs during this two hours will it not collect **unReachableString** ref ?. I assume it will not be Garbage Collected but then why? From where  **unReachableString**  is reachable ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896866/is-unused-object-available-for-garbage-collection-when-its-still-visible-in-sta

Comment: no its not duplicate .. question is related to is GC possible for an data of objects whose reference is yet not published.

Comment: Agreed, and the answer makes it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The String reference in SlowConstructor unReachableString is not reachable from any code for around two hours.

Incorrect.  The `SlowConstructor` object is *immediately* reachable from the thread that is in the process of constructing it.  So, therefore, is the string.

So that means that the String object won't be garbage collected before the constructor completes.

(And in fact, the string object corresponds to a String literal, and is therefore *also* reachable from the code (any code!) that assigns or applies a method to the literal.)

---

The concept of *reachability* includes any mechanism by which any current or future execution could use the object in question.  That includes cases where the object hasn't been assigned to a named variable or array element ... yet.

Comment: thanks, String was just for example. So you are saying the thread holds the reference to the SlowConstructor its just that we cannot access that reference programatically??

Comment: thanks Stephen, i know i was missing something .. thanks for clearing.

Comment: @veritas - yes.  That's what I'm saying.  In this case, the reference is not accessible programatically **yet** ... but it **will** be, and therefore it is reachable.

Answer (score 1):

As other have said GC is not going to affect a half-constructed object.  But why?  GC necessarily proceeds from a maximal set of root pointers.  Anything that can be reached from these roots is "protected" from GC.  This is either my marking as in mark-and-sweep collectors or by copying to a new active generation (arena) in a copying collector.  Roots consist of the runtime stack, machine (virtual or physical) registers, and global pointers.  When the constructor starts running, a pointer to the newly allocated record will be created.  Either it will be a root or accessible from a root. So the GC will not collect it.  Since the class instance under construction is accessible from a root, so is the string you're referring to.  Therefore it can't be collected either.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the threads weren't interrupted, your object will (eventually) instantiate, and (eventually) contain a value for `unReachableString`.

Strings are [interned](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), and would be subject to garbage collection only if nothing referred to it - kind of like how garbage collection works now.  The half-constructed object *does* refer to the interned string, so it would not be yet eligible for garbage collection.

I'm willing to bet that having fifty or so instances of this type floating around* wouldn't make a difference either - you then have fifty or so references to this string literal, and it wouldn't be yet eligible for garbage collection until these instances were eligible for garbage collection themselves.

<sup>*:  OH GOD NO PLEASE DON'T DO THIS IN ACTUAL CODE PLEASE</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It will not and should not be garbage collected.  Sleeping thread is still a **live** thread.

`Reachable` in GC context means the following: if we go through the `Stack` will we find a reference pointing to this object (memory space) on the `Heap`.

In you case the answer is **yes**.

Answer (score 0):

your logic is not correct, if thread is still alive it is in scope of method SlowConstructor. So JVM thinks that unReachableString  string can be used so Garbacge Collection does not touch that reference.

According to the code you can assume that unReachableString  is not used so it has to be Garbage Collected but JVM does not have intelligent logic to know the next. It just look at the scope of method and object reference.