# how to optimize large short-lived objects in jvm gc

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm

we meet a problem that about jvm gc. we have a large QPS application that jvm heap memory increased very fast. it will use more than 2g heap memory at a few seconds, then gc triggers that will collected more than 2g memory every time also very frequency。GC collect case like below picture.so this have two problems

1. gc need some time. what is more, it is frequent.
2. system will not stabilized.

[image]
I abstract the problem like below code. System allocate short-lived object fast.

```
public static void fun1() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        Byte[] bs = new Byte[1024 * 1024 * 5];
        bs = null;
    }
}
```

so, I have some questions:

1. many say that set object equals null will let gc thread collect easy。what the mean of that? we all know that minor GC is always triggered when the JVM is unable to allocate space for a new object.Thus, whether a object
   is null, gc will triggered only when space is not enough. so set object is null is not meaningful.
2. how to optimize this if exists large short-lived object? I means how to collect this objects not when young generation is not enough.

Any suggestions will help me.

Comment: Setting local variables to `null` indeed does rarely have any effect at all. Besides, I don’t get your actual problem nor what kind of solution you have in mind. The costs of a gc cycle depend on the amount of survivor objects, so if all your 2GiB objects are reclaimed within a single gc cycle, it can’t be that expensive. You may try smoothing the curve using the [Garbage-First Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/g1_gc.html), but a smoother curve does not imply a higher performance…

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to cache them. Instead of recreating them every time try to find a way to reuse already created ones.
Try to allocate more memory to your app with the option

```
-Xms8g -Xmx8g
```

gc is called when there is not enough memory so if you have more gc won't be called so often.

It's hard to suggest something valuable without the huge objects nature. Try to add an example of such an object as well as how to you create/call them.

If you have big byte arrays inside the short lived objects try to place them out of java (e.g. in a file and keep file path only).

Answer (score 0):

> many say that set object equals null will let gc thread collect easy

This question is covered by several others on stack overflow so i won't repeat those here. E.g. [Is unused object available for garbage collection when it's still visible in stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896866/is-unused-object-available-for-garbage-collection-when-its-still-visible-in-sta)

> how to optimize this if exists large short-lived object? I means how to collect this objects not when young generation is not enough.

Increase the size of the young generation. So that it can contain the object. Or use G1GC which can selectively collect regions containing such objects instead of the entire old generation.

You could also try using [direct byte buffers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect-int-) which will allocate the memory outside the heap thus reducing GC pressure. But the memory will stay allocated until the Buffers pointing to the memory get collected.

Other than that you should redesign your code to avoid such frequent, large allocations. Often one can use object pools or thread-local variables as scratch memory.

Comment: If use G1GC, with Byte[] bs = new Byte[1024 * 1024 * 5];. This may be overrun the default `G1HeapRegionSize`, with default region size at one 2^n closest to xmx/2048, but must >=1M and <= 32M. Overrun will cause long time `Humongous Allocation`. Be sure to change the `-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=Xm` twice larger than array allocation need. And further, under my test G1GC is less effective than ParNewGC with small SurvivorRatio, in heavy memory consume scene.